# Format print statement pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, format

I have a pandas data frame like so:

```
[in]print(lang_sorted)

[out]
      frequency
lang           
en          585
ar          179
es          147
ja          114
pt          113
und         109
tr           82
fr           43
ko           21
```

How can I print the data frame to a text file without any headers or spaces- so that the format is 'lang,freq'\n where each line is a new line with no spaces or breaks in the file (and no ' ')?

I tried:
    `print("{},{}".format(lang_sorted))`
but this threw an error:
    `IndexError: tuple index out of range`
and also:
`print(lang_sorted.applymap("{0:.2f}".format))` but this just turned my frquencies to floats.

The file I am printing this into is organized like such:

```
# Create the twitter analytics text file
with io.open("twitter_analytics.txt","w",encoding='utf8') as twitter_analytics:    
    # Number of events
    print(len(data))
    # Number of tweets
    print(len(tweets))
    # Frequency of tweets by language
    print("{},{}".format(lang_sorted))
    twitter_analytics.close()
```

Comment: Why are you manually closing `twitter_analytics` when you're already using a context manager?

Comment: lol- i dont know?

Comment: OK, that line is redundant. The file gets closed when you exit the scope of the `with io.open(...) as twitter_analytics:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.to_csv`.

`df.to_csv('your-file.csv')`

Or without headers:

```
df.to_csv('your-file.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: Then name the file `your-file.txt`. It's the same thing.

Comment: @zsad512 CSV is a plain text file. Try `print(df.to_csv())` and you'll see its contents. You can change the extension of your file as you like.

Comment: The other issue is that the file is a larger file with other print statements in it.  Please see my edit.

Comment: @zsad512 Don't give it a file name then. Just use `print(df.to_csv())`  or `print(df.to_csv(header=False))`

Comment: If there's already data in the file you don't want to overwrite, use `df.to_csv('your-file.txt', header=False, mode='a')`

Comment: how can I get rid of the new line at the end of the last row of the csv?

Comment: I don't think there's an automatic way to do it. I guess you could output it to a string and then slice off the result without the newline and then write it to the file. like `csv_data = df.to_csv()[:-1]    output_file.write(csv_data)`